# How do you figure out how deep the water table is somewhere?

Tags: measuring

I'm looking at buying some land, and was wondering how to figure out how deep it is to the water table so I can know what I can put in a location in the yard.

Comment: Your well test should give the depth of the water table. If it is spring water, close to the surface close to the spring . If city water a hole will need to be drilled and probes dropped, that's how well testers do it.

Comment: This year we have a low water table, and I'm looking at it from the surveyor's perspective, so I can know what rows I can put into the surface water, not a deep water area.

Comment: You can try asking the town what depth is typical in that neighborhood, but the details of what is  under *this* property may change the answer.

Comment: I talked to the neighbors, and they said they have a lot of problems with even apple trees, because the water is on average about 2 feet higher this year than normal years.

Comment: @EdBeal I'm walking fields tomorrow with a realtor to see if the land would be a good buy to set up a farm, or not.